# How to make dynamic table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to create a dynamic html table and i've not been able to do it yet.

i will give what ive done

[image]

and this is the code

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="tr">
        <th>Students Name</th>
        <th>Average</th>
    </tr>
    {% for student in teacherStudents %}
    <tr id="tr2">
        <td id="td">{{ student.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<button type="button" value="" class="save" onclick="doTheInsert()" title="Insert New Cell" id="save">&plus;&nbsp;Insert New Cell</button>

<button type="button" value="" class="save" onclick="undoTheInsert()" title="Undo Recent Action" id="unsave">&times;&nbsp;Undo Recent Action</button>

<script>
    var count = 0;

    function doTheInsert() {
        let header = $.find("tr[id='tr']")[0];
        header.append("<th data-id='header'><input type='date'></th>");
        let rows = $.find("tr[id='tr2']");
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].append("<td data-id='row'><input type='text'/></td>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

what i want is if the teacher click the button it will add textbox under the date, depending on the number of students how many textboxes to add

for example i click twice the button Insert New Cell

this is the result I want, (i will make static result to clarify what i want)

[image]

what result ive got

[image]

UPDATE:
when I tried the answer of Sir dirkgroten I got this

the date will appear between the Students Name and Average

[image]

Comment: The problem is `[0]` and `[i]`. By indexing your jquery elements like that, you're actually getting javascript DOM nodes. The function `append()` in javascript also exists and will append the blob (i.e. not html) as text.

Comment: Try to remove the `[0]` when you define `header`. And instead of looping through the rows, just `rows.append("<td ...>")`. That will use the jquery `append()` which allows html.

Comment: I don't get it sir

Comment: Note that you shouldn't have multiple rows with the same id. This might lead to unexpected behavior. An id is unique for the entire page. Use a class instead.

Comment: `let header=$.find("tr[id='tr']");`

Comment: I tried this let header=$.find("tr[id='tr']"); I got no result

Comment: why text appeard instead of textbox or date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.append()` is applied to a javascript DOM node instead of jQuery element, because you index into the jQuery elements.

For example, `let header = $("tr#tr")` gives you all `<tr id="tr">` elements. When you do `header[0]` this isn't a jQuery element anymore but the javascript node. So `append()` is not the same function you expect:

- In javascript, `ParentNode.append(<string>)` appends the actual string, as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).
- In jQuery, `elem.append(<string>)` appends the HTML, if the string is an htmlString, as explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Your code should be like this:

```
function doTheInsert()
    {
        let header=$("tr#tr");  // same as $.find("tr[id='tr2']")
        header.append("<th data-id='header'><input type='date'></th>");

        let rows=$("tr#tr2");
        rows.append("<td data-id='row'><input type='text'/></td>");
    }
```

Comment: I answered your problem that the content you appended wasn't html content. Now it's a question of being smarter about where to append or insert. Use a different jquery selector to append/insert at the correct location.

Comment: Of course if you "append" as the name says this will add the element at the end of the selected element. You can also "insert", e.g. by adding an id to your "average" column and selecting that instead.

Comment: Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) for the various methods of prepending or appending or inserting. And [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/).

Comment: it so complicated